# connecting to internet over proxy

Tags: software-center

We have proxy-server, I was able to set up network connection and mozilla works perfectly, it prompts for login/password and when logged-in it works, but when I try to download any software from repository or to search for updates, the system does not connect to internet.

It does not prompt for login/password, as it does in Windows Update Center.

What is it that I need to configure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set Proxy by adding following lines in `/etc/profile`

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyhost:port/ 
export ftp_proxy=http://username:password@proxyhost:port/
```

Then just reload profile using `source /etc/profile`. after this you can use :

```
apt-get update
```

If you are still facing same issue, then edit "`/etc/apt/apt.conf`"  and add below entry:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://username:password@proxyhost:port/";
```

Comment: Rahul Patil, I did as you suggested. Running "apt-get update" in terminal results in long list of ignored and erroneus web-adderesses like "Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease" and "Er http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal/main Sources 407 Unauthorized". What's wrong now? And how I can download and install applications from repository? For example I look for gXNeur using Ubuntu application center. It locates gXNeur as available from source "universe". I click use this source. Progress icon starts running, then it stops and prompts "Check internet connection". Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: I have updated another option...

Comment: if it working then select answer as correct, this is way to say thanks on this site :P